# integrate $ \frac {7x^2 + 2x − 7}{ x^3 − x}$ dx

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I keep messing up with the integration part of this I think. Before that I have to factor out the $x$ on the bottom, and then set up the $A$ and $B$ right?

Evaluate the integral. (Remember to use $\ln|u|$ where appropriate. Use $C$ for the constant of integration.)
$$\int\frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x^3-x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
As $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x+1)(x-1),$

Using [Partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)

$$\frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac A{x+1}+\frac Bx+\frac C{x-1}$$

Multiply either sides by $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x+1)(x-1)$

and compare the coefficients of the different power of $x$  to find $A,B,C$

Finally use $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x+m}=\ln|x+m|+C$

Comment: Multyply by $\large x + 1$ in both members and take the limit $\large x \to -1$. That yields $\large A$. Similarly with the other factors.

Comment: @FelixMarin, in fact, after multiplication by $x^3-x$ we can forget about the denominator for the time being and set $x=0,1,-1$ in the resulting relation to find $A,B,C$.

Comment: That's fine. I was thinking in Mittag-Leffler.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Apply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure

$$ \frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x^3-x} = \frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x(x^2-1)} = \frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x(x-1)(x+1)} $$

$$ \frac{7x^2+2x-7}{x(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{(x-1)} + \frac{C}{(x+1)} $$

You can obtain A,B,C by setting the value of x are 1,-1,0 respectively and compare the coefficient of different power of x i.e 2,1 and 0.

$$ \int (\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{(x-1)} + \frac{C}{(x+1)}) dx = \int \frac{A}{x} + \int \frac{B}{(x-1)} + \int \frac{C}{(x+1)}$$

Now, apply this, to get your final answer

$$ \int \frac{1}{x+k} = ln|x+k| + C$$

Comment: if we set $x=0,-1,1$ we shall have $0$ in the denominators in some terms of either sides